# show alert message when closing a window? Not Working

Tags: javascript

I want to show alert before closing a prticluar tab. I have tried different codes over here but couldn't suceeded somwhow.. could somebody guide me where I am going wrong.. 
My Last try was :

```
<html>  
  <head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js" />

  </head>
  <body>




  <script>
window.onbeforeunload = function (event) {
  var message = 'Sure you want to leave?';
  if (typeof event == 'undefined') {
    event = window.event;
  }
  if (event) {
    event.returnValue = message;
  }
  return message;
}
</script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depending on your browser your code *works*. I've updated the snippet below so it always sets a `returnValue` which is required by some browsers. If you click the `Run code snippet` button below and attempt to close the tab you'll get an alert asking if you're sure you want to leave.

However what's important to know is that [most browsers have removed the ability to serve custom messages](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowEventHandlers/onbeforeunload#Browser_compatibility) on these alerts for security purposes.

```js
window.onbeforeunload = function (event) {
   event.preventDefault();
   event.returnValue = '';
};
```

Comment: I dont need custom messages either.. I will run ajax call on close, but the weired thing is... it doesn't work on my browsers.. chrome/firefox.

Comment: I've modified the example, my guess is because you're not setting a `returnValue` which is required by some browsers.

Comment: when I run this code and try to close the browser on SO it asks me if I want to leave this site or not.. but doesn't asks on my local file .. is it some kind of issue ?